# Unresponsive buttons in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT application, with some buttons. These buttons seem to be unresponsive sometimes, i.e., clicking on them does nothing. Has anyone faced this problem before ? is it to do with the browser compatibility ?

PS: I am running the GWT development mode on MAC OS if that is relevant at all.

Comment: Add a sample of what doesn't work - there are ways to add buttons to the page in such a way as to make them not respond, but the problem is that there are _many_ ways... Make a simple EntryPoint with buttons and handlers that don't respond, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this in the past when an element in the widget hierarchy was added via getElement().appendChild() instead of .add()

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/78360 for a related thread.

-Clint